# customised tag is not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sandbox

I am trying to create a simple class in reactjs as shown below in the code. i am using sandbox. when i run code, i get the below posted errors.
please let me know how to fix it

**code**:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import createReactClass from "create-react-class";

class HelloMessage extends React.Component {
render() {
return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
}
    }

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage name="Helloo Welt" />);

export default HelloMessage;
```

**error**:

```
 Target container is not a DOM element.
```

Comment: ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage name="Helloo Welt" />, rootElement);

Answer (score 0):

The second param is missing for `render`.

It should dom element where react going to place the html for rendering.

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage name="Helloo Welt" />, rootElement);
```

Working [`codesandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/s/719wv2n190)